# Fill a DataSet with nearly 20,0000 records using SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, performance

I want to fill a `DataSet` with 20,0000 records using a `SqlDataAdapter` by using this code:

```
adapter.Fill(dataset);
```

If I fill a `DataSet` this way it takes a long time. Is there anything wrong with this?

This is my code:

```
connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
connection.Open(); 

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_DMS_Report_Generate", connection); 
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@XML", reportCriteria.XML); 
command.CommandTimeout = 1000; 

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command); 
adapter.Fill(resultSet); 

return resultSet.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Please, post the complete code which you have tried. Then only we come to know whats your problem is.

Comment: Please, review your question. Don't get it.

Comment: Yes it will take some time to load. Please, write what is your point, what problems you have?

Comment: 20 thousand or 200 thousand?

Comment: What is *too long* ?

Comment: Off-topic: This is a matter of style and won't have any influence the speed of `adapter.Fill`, but do use `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` instead of `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings` for accessing connection strings from `App.config`.

Comment: First, if the above code is exactly what you're doing, how do you know that it's the call to `adapter.Fill` that's taking a long time? Have you measured the time taken for this one particular call? How long exactly did it take? What factors could influence DB speed (slow network connection to DB server, command timeout not being honored, etc.)?

Comment: adapter.Fill opens and closes the DB connection automatically so connection.Open() is redundant. Also if you're returning a datatable vs dataset why not fill a datatable instead

Comment: Is this 20,000 or 200,000 records?

Answer (score 3):

I would say the C# is fine, it's your database that is the issue.  Is the Stored procedure optimized?  Are the tables in the proper normalization?  Are your primary keys & foreign keys set up properly? (you should get the point by now)

Start there first since really everything is there.

Comment: +1: right, there isn't much more you can change with this sort of operation.